# Symfony2 - Set value of checkboxes in form from ORM DQL

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I'm creating a form that is supposed to filter a custom query list in Symfony2(ver 2.3) using LexikFilter Bundle.
Project setup:

1. Symfony2 :2.3.7
2. LexikFilter Bundle : 3.0.8
3. Doctrine ORM 2.4

The project consist of entities having a n:m relationship (Parents-Training) , the Parent Filter Form embed a Training filter form as below:

```
class MyParentsType extends AbstractType
{

    private $repository ;

    function __construct($repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository; // store it, we are going to use it later
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'parents_filter';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Firstname', 'filter_text', array('condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_BOTH,))
                ->add('Lastname', 'filter_text', array('condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_BOTH,))
                ->add('trainings','filter_collection_adapter', array(
                                            'type'=> new MyTrainingType2($this->repository),
                                            'default_data' => new ArrayCollection(),
                                            'add_shared'=> function(FilterBuilderExecuterInterface $qbe){
                                                $closure = function(QueryBuilder $filterBuilder, $alias, $joinAlias, Expr $expr){
                                                     $filterBuilder ->leftJoin($alias.'.options',$joinAlias);
                                                };
                                                $qbe->addOnce($qbe->getAlias().'.options','opt',$closure);
                                            },
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' =>'tuto\LexikTestBundle\Entity\Parents',
                'csrf_protection' => false,
                'validation_groups' => ['filtering'] // avoid NotBlank() constraint-related message
            ]
        );
    }
```

and the Training filter form:

```
class MyTrainingType2 extends AbstractType
{

    private $repository ;

    function __construct($repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository; // store it, we are going to use it later
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'training_filter';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Title', 'filter_text', array('condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_BOTH,))
                ->add('Location', 'filter_choice', array( 'choice_list' => new ChoiceList($this->repository->getLocationList(),$this->repository->getLocationList()),
                                                          'expanded'=> true,
                                                          'multiple'=>true,
                                                          )
                    );

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' =>'tuto\LexikTestBundle\Entity\Training',
                'csrf_protection' => false,
                'validation_groups' => ['filtering'] // avoid NotBlank() constraint-related message
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the `getLocationList()` method of the `Training Repository`:

```
 public function getLocationList()
    {   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.Location')//
        ->orderBy('t.Location','asc')
        ->distinct(true);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

The filter does display the checkboxes but the value field is set to the column name `Location`. Here a snippet of the array being returned by the `getArrayResult`

```
array (size=199)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Location' => string '‘Arīshah' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Location' => string 'Abuja' (length=5)
```

I would like to have it returned as :

```
 0 => 
    array (size=1)
      '‘Arīshah' => string '‘Arīshah' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Abuja' => string 'Abuja' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
$locations = array_map(function(array $location){
                 return $location['Location'];
             }, $this->repository->getLocationList());

// and then in your form definition:

'choice' => ['choices' => array_combine($locations, $locations)]
```

Comment: Can you expand on the code given a little more? because i did create a class `Location` with a field of the same name . However, i get an error saying that the  `Closure expect Type of Location but array given`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that your repository was returning some sort of "Location" entity. What's that repository and what kind of array is returning when calling "getLocationList()"?

Comment: A nested array (I've updated the question with the array type returned and the DQL used).

Comment: I've modified the answer slightly